# System.JSON.deserialize not covering Parser class

Tags: apex, json, code-coverage

I am deserializing a response with a class. In my test class i am passing dummy JSON String, but its covering all the lines in class.

```
public class CustomerAccount  {

    public class OrgDetails{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String orgId {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String org_name {get;set;}
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String account_no {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled 
    public List<OrgDetails> orgDetail {get;set;}

    public static CustomerAccount  parse(String json) {
        return (CustomerAccount ) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CustomerAccount .class);
    }
```

}

When I am calling parse with dummy JSON then its only covering parse method and one other property.

Calling only `parse()` method is not enough for covering this `class(CustomerAccount)`?

Comment: You _aren't_ calling `parse()`, so it won't be covered. I'm having a hard time following your question. Are there other executable lines of code in the class `CustomerAccount`? Variable declarations are not coverable.

Comment: @DavidReed i have edited my questing, my class is similar to this. When i am calling parse() with dummy json then its not covering all the variables. 
Do i need to call this class to cover all the variables, JSON.deserialize will not cover all the lines?

Comment: Please review the section "Properties" of the question linked by identigral, which covers this situation.